# ColdFusion 11 seems to render definitions for superclass as well as class

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-11

In a ColdFusion application, I have a class called ProjectBeanService that extends another class called AjaxBeanService.

In CF8, where the code seems to be working properly, when debugging the application in IE, I see this rendered JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _cf_ProjectBeanService=ColdFusion.AjaxProxy.init('/components/ProjectBeanService.cfc','ProjectBeanService');
    _cf_ProjectBeanService.prototype.get=function(sPropertyName,sBeanType,nID,sSection,nRevision) { return ColdFusion.AjaxProxy.invoke(this, "get", {sPropertyName:sPropertyName,sBeanType:sBeanType,nID:nID,sSection:sSection,nRevision:nRevision});};
    _cf_ProjectBeanService.prototype.getAll=function(sBeanType,nID,sSection,nRevision) { return ColdFusion.AjaxProxy.invoke(this, "getAll", {sBeanType:sBeanType,nID:nID,sSection:sSection,nRevision:nRevision});};
    _cf_ProjectBeanService.prototype.set=function(sPropertyName,oPropertyValue,sBeanType,nID,sSection,nRevision) { return ColdFusion.AjaxProxy.invoke(this, "set", {sPropertyName:sPropertyName,oPropertyValue:oPropertyValue,sBeanType:sBeanType,nID:nID,sSection:sSection,nRevision:nRevision});};
</script>
```

However, when I try to run the same application under CF11, both the class methods and the superclass methods are rendered:

```
<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
    var _cf_ProjectBeanService=ColdFusion.AjaxProxy.init('/components/ProjectBeanService.cfc','ProjectBeanService');
    _cf_ProjectBeanService.prototype.get=function(sPropertyName,sBeanType,nID,sSection,nRevision) { return ColdFusion.AjaxProxy.invoke(this, "get","4789898A8974AC60", {sPropertyName:sPropertyName,sBeanType:sBeanType,nID:nID,sSection:sSection,nRevision:nRevision});};
    _cf_ProjectBeanService.prototype.getAll=function(sBeanType,nID,sSection,nRevision) { return ColdFusion.AjaxProxy.invoke(this, "getAll","4789898A8974AC60", {sBeanType:sBeanType,nID:nID,sSection:sSection,nRevision:nRevision});};
    _cf_ProjectBeanService.prototype.set=function(sPropertyName,oPropertyValue,sBeanType,nID,sSection,nRevision) { return ColdFusion.AjaxProxy.invoke(this, "set","4789898A8974AC60", {sPropertyName:sPropertyName,oPropertyValue:oPropertyValue,sBeanType:sBeanType,nID:nID,sSection:sSection,nRevision:nRevision});};
    _cf_ProjectBeanService.prototype.get=function(sBeanName,sPropertyName) { return ColdFusion.AjaxProxy.invoke(this, "get","4789898A8974AC60", {sBeanName:sBeanName,sPropertyName:sPropertyName});};
    _cf_ProjectBeanService.prototype.destroySessionBean=function(sBeanName) { return ColdFusion.AjaxProxy.invoke(this, "destroySessionBean","4789898A8974AC60", {sBeanName:sBeanName});};
    _cf_ProjectBeanService.prototype.createSessionBean=function(sBeanName,sBeanType,sDAOName) { return ColdFusion.AjaxProxy.invoke(this, "createSessionBean","4789898A8974AC60", {sBeanName:sBeanName,sBeanType:sBeanType,sDAOName:sDAOName});};
    _cf_ProjectBeanService.prototype.getAll=function(sBeanName) { return ColdFusion.AjaxProxy.invoke(this, "getAll","4789898A8974AC60", {sBeanName:sBeanName});};
    _cf_ProjectBeanService.prototype.getSessionBean=function(sBeanName) { return ColdFusion.AjaxProxy.invoke(this, "getSessionBean","4789898A8974AC60", {sBeanName:sBeanName});};
    _cf_ProjectBeanService.prototype.set=function(sBeanName,sPropertyName,oPropertyValue) { return ColdFusion.AjaxProxy.invoke(this, "set","4789898A8974AC60", {sBeanName:sBeanName,sPropertyName:sPropertyName,oPropertyValue:oPropertyValue});};
    _cf_ProjectBeanService.prototype.reInitSessionBean=function(sBeanName,argument1,argument2,argument3,argument4) { return ColdFusion.AjaxProxy.invoke(this, "reInitSessionBean","4789898A8974AC60", {sBeanName:sBeanName,argument1:argument1,argument2:argument2,argument3:argument3,argument4:argument4});};
/* ]]> */</script>
```

In this block of code, notice how after the "set" function is defined, it is defined again (and according to the superclass definition). It seems to me that ColdFusion 11 is rendering this superclass, whereas CF 8 did not.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

Here is a stripped down version of the application, wherein I was able to reproduce the error.

/components/AbstractAjax.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="AbstractAjax">

    <cffunction name="sendError" access="private" returntype="void">
        <cfargument name="sErrCode" type="string" required="yes" />
        <cfargument name="sErrMsg" type="string" required="yes" />      
        <cfif IsNumeric(arguments.sErrCode)>
            <cfscript>
                GetPageContext().getResponse().sendError(arguments.sErrCode,arguments.sErrMsg);
         </cfscript>
      <cfelse>
        <cfscript>
            GetPageContext().getResponse().sendError(555,arguments.sErrCode & ' - ' & arguments.sErrMsg);
         </cfscript>
      </cfif>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

/components/AjaxBeanService.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="AjaxBeanService" extends="com.AbstractAjax">

    <cffunction name="createSessionBean" access="remote" returntype="struct">
        <cfargument name="sBeanName" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="sBeanType" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="sDAOName" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfset var oBean = StructNew() />
        <cfset var oBeanArguments = ARGUMENTS />
        <cfset var oDAO = application[sDAOName] />

        <cftry>
            <cfset oBean = createObject("component","com." & sBeanType) />

             <!--- delete first 3 elements from arguments array --->
            <cfset ArrayDeleteAt(oBeanArguments,1) />
            <cfset ArrayDeleteAt(oBeanArguments,1) />
            <cfset ArrayDeleteAt(oBeanArguments,1) />

            <!--- make the DAO object the first argument --->
            <cfset ArrayPrepend(oBeanArguments,oDAO) />

            <cfset oBean.init.apply(oBean,oBeanArguments) />
            <cfset SESSION.beans[sBeanName] = oBean />
            <cfreturn oBean.getAll() />
            <cfcatch type="any">
                <cfset sendError(cfcatch.ErrorCode,cfcatch.message) />
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="destroySessionBean" access="remote" returntype="struct">
        <cfargument name="sBeanName" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfset rc = StructDelete(SESSION.beans, "#sBeanName#", "True")>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="reInitSessionBean" access="remote" returntype="struct">
        <cfargument name="sBeanName" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="argument1" type="any" required="no" default="">
        <cfargument name="argument2" type="any" required="no" default="">
        <cfargument name="argument3" type="any" required="no" default="">
        <cfargument name="argument4" type="any" required="no" default="">
       <cfset var oBean = StructNew() />
        <cftry>
            <cfset oBean = getSessionBean(sBeanName) />           
            <cfset oBean.init(oBean.getDAO(),argument1,argument2,argument3,argument4) />
            <cfset SESSION.beans[sBeanName] = oBean />
            <cfreturn oBean.getAll() />
            <cfcatch type="any">
                <cfset sendError(cfcatch.ErrorCode,cfcatch.message) />
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="getSessionBean" access="remote" returntype="any">
        <cfargument name="sBeanName" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfset var oBean = StructNew() />
        <cfif StructKeyExists(SESSION.beans,sBeanName) >
            <cflock scope="session" type="readonly" timeout="5" throwontimeout="yes">
                <cfset oBean = Duplicate(SESSION.beans[sBeanName]) />
            </cflock>
        </cfif>
        <cfif StructIsEmpty(oBean)>
            <cfthrow errorcode="500" message="No bean found by the name '#sBeanname#'" />
        <cfelse>
            <cfreturn oBean />
        </cfif>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="set" access="remote" returntype="void">
        <cfargument name="sBeanName" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="sPropertyName" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="oPropertyValue" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfset var oBean = StructNew() />
        <cftry>
            <cfset oBean = getSessionBean(sBeanName) />
            <cfset oBean.set(sPropertyName,oPropertyValue) />
            <cfcatch type="any">
                 <cfset sendError(cfcatch.ErrorCode,cfcatch.message) />
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
     </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="get" access="remote" returntype="any">
        <cfargument name="sBeanName" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="sPropertyName" type="string" required="yes">

        <cfset var value = "" />
        <cfset var oBean = StructNew() />

        <cftry>      
            <cfset oBean = getSessionBean(sBeanName) />
            <cfset value = oBean.get(sPropertyName) />
            <cfreturn value />

            <cfcatch type="any">
                    <cfset sendError(cfcatch.ErrorCode,cfcatch.message) />
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
     </cffunction>

     <cffunction name="getAll" access="remote" returntype="struct">
        <cfargument name="sBeanName" type="string" required="yes">

        <cfset var oBean = StructNew() />
        <cfset var oStruct = structNew() />

        <cftry>      
            <cfset oBean = getSessionBean(sBeanName) />
            <cfset oStruct = oBean.getAll() />
            <cfreturn oStruct />

            <cfcatch type="any">
                  <cfset sendError(cfcatch.ErrorCode,cfcatch.message) />
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
     </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

/components/ProjectBeanService.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="ProjectBeanService" extends="com.AjaxBeanService">

    <cffunction name="getBean" access="private" returntype="any">
        <cfargument name="sBeanType" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="nID" type="numeric" required="yes" hint="ProjectID or ImpactID">
        <cfargument name="sSection" type="string" required="no" hint="ProjectSection or ImpactSection" default="">
        <cfargument name="nRevision" type="numeric" required="no" hint="Commitment Revision" default="0">

        <cfset var oBean = createObject("component","com." & sBeanType).init(nID,sSection,nRevision)  />

        <cfreturn oBean />

    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="set" access="remote" returntype="void">
        <cfargument name="sPropertyName" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="oPropertyValue" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="sBeanType" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="nID" type="numeric" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="sSection" type="string" required="no" default="">
        <cfargument name="nRevision" type="numeric" required="no" default="0">
        <cfset var oBean = StructNew() />
        <cftry>

            <cfset oBean = getBean(sBeanType, nID, sSection,nRevision) />
            <cfset oBean.set(sPropertyName,oPropertyValue) />
            <cfcatch type="any">
                 <cfset sendError(cfcatch.ErrorCode,cfcatch.message) />
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
     </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="get" access="remote" returntype="any">
        <cfargument name="sPropertyName" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="sBeanType" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="nID" type="numeric" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="sSection" type="string" required="no" default="">
        <cfargument name="nRevision" type="numeric" required="no" default="0">

        <cfset var value = "" />
        <cfset var oBean = StructNew() />

        <cftry>      
            <cfset oBean = getBean(sBeanType,nID,sSection,nRevision) />
            <cfset value = oBean.get(sPropertyName) />
            <cfreturn value />

            <cfcatch type="any">
                    <cfset sendError(cfcatch.ErrorCode,cfcatch.message) />
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
     </cffunction>

     <cffunction name="getAll" access="remote" returntype="struct">
        <cfargument name="sBeanType" type="string" required="no" default="ProjectBean">
        <cfargument name="nID" type="numeric" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="sSection" type="string" required="no" default="">
        <cfargument name="nRevision" type="numeric" required="no" default="0">

        <cfset var oBean = StructNew() />
        <cfset var oStruct = structNew() />

        <cftry>      
            <cfset oBean = getBean(sBeanType,nID,sSection,nRevision) />
            <cfset oStruct = oBean.getAll() />
            <cfreturn oStruct />

            <cfcatch type="any">
                  <cfset sendError(cfcatch.ErrorCode,cfcatch.message) />
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
     </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

/Application.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfscript>
        this.mappings["/com"] = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) & "\components\";    
   </cfscript> 
</cfcomponent>
```

/index.cfm:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>    
   <cfajaxproxy cfc="com.ProjectBeanService" jsclassname="ProjectBeanService">   
</head>
<body>
<span>This is a test.</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the *actual problem* this is causing you? Provided the subclass method proxies are set after the base class ones, won't they simply replace them?

Comment: If that were the case, there would be no problem. However, the subclass method proxies are being set before the class ones, so the effect is that the class methods are overriding the subclass methods.

Comment: Cool, and sorry you did say that. Could you knock together a stand-alone repro of this, so we can test it locally? Two pared-back CFC files and a CFM file.

Comment: Yes, I've got a stand alone stripped-down app set up on both CF8 and CF11. I have reproduced the issue.

Comment: That's lovely. *can you please include it in your question*. The end result of the code is not so useful compared to the code that causes it.

Comment: Sorry about that - I've updated the question.

Comment: Brilliant. I'm pissed as a weasel at the moment, but I'll check this out when I get back on deck tomorrow

Comment: No problem. I appreciate the help.

Comment: After doing some more research, it appears that there was a bug in CF8 that prevented functions marked remote from being inherited via CFAJAXPROXY, and the bug was to be fixed in CF9. So it's safe to assume that all methods are showing up now due to the fix. However, that still doesn't explain why the parent class methods' proxies are declared last, overriding the child class methods. http://www.raymondcamden.com/2009/05/11/CFAJAXPROXY-and-Extended-CFCs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, the only answer I have come up with is that this must be a bug in CF11, so I was able to "fix" it by marking the methods in the parent class as having access "public" rather than "remote". I do not yet know what unintended consequences this could have, but it seems to have fixed my problem. If anyone has a better suggestion, please let me know, and I'll give the answer check to that person.